# uninstall pycharm from ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, snap, pycharm

Please when I want to uninstall Pycharm Community this message appear.

[image]

I use Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Can you add the message please ?

Comment: thanks for reply.

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request

Comment: Please open a terminal and show us the complete output of the command `snap list`

Comment: Name    Version            Rev   Developer      Notes
core    16-2.29.3          3440  canonical      core
vscode  1.17.2-1508162334  19    flexiondotorg  classic

Comment: please can I add an image in comments?

Answer (score 5):

I would begin by ensuring Pycharm Community is installed correctly in terminal.

```
sudo snap refresh    
snap list
```

this should list pycharm-communtiy, if it is not listed, type:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-communtiy --classic
```

now to stop the program's services (if any) so they do not conflict. type:

```
sudo snap stop pycharm-community
```

and disable the snap:

```
sudo snap disable pycharm-community
```

and finally remove it

```
sudo snap remove pycharm-community
```

Ensure it is removed by

```
snap list
```